# reading key value pairs from a file where value has new lines

Tags: bash

I have a file which has data in file.txt as

```
key1=this
is
the
value.
```

i need to fetch the value of key1 in a variable($var) with the same format.
for eg.

```
echo "$var"
this
is
the
value.
```

i tried the following

```
bash-4.1$ sed '/^\#/d' ./file.txt | grep "key1"  | sed 's/^.*=//'
this
```

Any suggestions on this. I have keys before and after key1

Comment: How do you know when the value ends?

Comment: Is there another key after this one or the file content is only for key1?

Comment: yes there is another key before and after key1

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In bash the value assigned to variable can be in multiple lines when they are quoted. So your file content should be as below

```
key1="this
is
the
value."
```

Please note that we now a double quote

Now we can do a simple echo command and get the formatted value

```
 echo "$key1"
 this
 is
 the
 value.
```

Comment: ok even if i add the double quotes... how do i read the value of key1 from file.txt to my local variable $var. i tried bash-4.1$ sed '/^\#/d' ./file.txt | grep "key1"  | sed 's/^.*=//'. it prints only the 1st line..

Comment: any suggestion on how to get this?